# Disallowing certain values with properties

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a text box in an MVVM WPF application, bound to this property:

```
private decimal _cartPayment;
public decimal CartPayment {
    get { return _cartPayment; }
    set { 
        _cartPayment = value;
        this.NotifyPropertyChanged("CartPayment");
    }
}
```

My question is, how do I limit the range of values allowed? For example it should only be two decimal places.

In a similar issue I have another `ushort` property called `Quantity`, The value should not be 0.

How do I set it so that when the user types something illegal (e.g more than 2 decimal places for the first example, and 0 for the Quantity field), the control will be surrounded by a red border like so?

[image]

Comment: Take a look at the following link; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd901590%28v=vs.95%29.aspx You could use `regex` expressions to make a limit on your property.

Comment: Take a look into the [Data Validation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx#data_validation) article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [IDataErrorInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.idataerrorinfo.aspx) interface. You can use this interface in combination with XAML to show user the validation errors on UI.

Google it you will find lot of samples and tutorials. For start take a look at [Validation made easy with IDataErrorInfo](http://codeblitz.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/wpf-validation-made-easy-with-idataerrorinfo/)

Answer (score 1):

you can use [DataAnnotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.aspx)

sample

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

[Required] //tells your XAML that this value is required
[RegularExpression(@"^[0-9\s]{0,40}$")]// only numbers and between 0 and 40 digits allowed
public int yourIntValue
{
    get { return myValue; }
    set { myValue= value; }
}
```

ok here an komplett example

### XAML

```
<Window x:Class="DataAnnotations.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Width="100" Height="25"
            Text="{Binding Path=CartPayment, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" Name="txtPayment" Margin="22,20,381,266" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

### Codebehind

```
using System.Windows;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace DataAnnotations
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaktionslogik für MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new Cl();
        }
    }

    public class Cl
    {
        private decimal _cartPayment;
        [Required]
        [RegularExpression(@"^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$")]
        public decimal CartPayment
        {
            get { 
                return _cartPayment; }
            set
            {
                _cartPayment = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sure i used in my application i use it together with `IDataErrorInfo` so i'm able to avoid all [THIS](http://codeblitz.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/wpf-validation-made-easy-with-idataerrorinfo/) Stuff (see `this[string columnName]`)

Comment: @Clemens [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14748357/multiple-validation-per-metadate-fails) you can see how i use it together

Comment: @Clemens it works just fine (I use it within my application), as long as within your binding you add `ValidatesOnDataErrors`. Its a very simple and easy way of validating properties and alot quicker to implement then IDataErrorInfo. Very flexible also, due to its regex expressions, so you could manipulate it to what ever you want the property to do!

Comment: @WiiMaxx
I tried this, but it did not work for me:
`<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=CartPayment, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"`

My regular expression: `[RegularExpression(@"^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$")]` . This is used on a decimal property.

Comment: @Edwin but your XAML looks fine did you set the Metadata?

Comment: @Edwin i'm talking about the things in the square brackets ;)

Comment: @Edwin as easiest test use `[Required]`

Comment: @WiiMaxx Sorry about the external link, but here is my property:
http://pastebin.com/6zQ3KrUV

Comment: @Edwin don't know whats wrong in your case so i added a working example if remove the 0 you get your Border ^^

Comment: @WiiMaxx I tried your sample code, but the regular expression doesn't seem to work. (I typed in 100.003)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30685/discussion-between-wiimaxx-and-edwin)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ValidationRules`

For more information : 
[system.windows.data.binding.validationrules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.data.binding.validationrules.aspx)